# python3: how to convert "\u3000" (ideographic space) to "　"?

Tags: python-3.x, python-unicode

japanese.txt

```
あかさ
あいうえ　お
いい
```

mycode.py

```
with open('japanese.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    old = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]

send_mail(from, to, title, message=f"hello {old}!")
```

Then I receive mail like this

```
hello ['あかさ', 'あいうえ\u3000お', 'いい']!
```

What I want to mail is this

```
hello ['あかさ', 'あいうえ　お', 'いい']!
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `My mail message is "hello あか\u3000さた!"` - do you see this content in received mail, or this is just debug output in console?

Comment: In Jupyter and in my console, the command `a = "あか　さた"; print(f"hello {a}!")` works without showing the `\u3000`. In what application are you running your code ?

Comment: str.replace(u'\u3000',u' ')

Comment: @awesoon Sorry the pre-edited version of my question was my mistake. I edited my question more precisely

Comment: @pyOliv I get the same result from your code also in my computer. Sorry. I edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

list's `__str__` method uses `repr` on elements, therefore you're seeing `\u3000` in your mail. Just convert list to string yourself:

```
In [28]: l = ['あかさ', 'あいうえ\u3000お', 'いい']

In [29]: print(', '.join(map(str, l)))
あかさ, あいうえ　お, いい
```

If you're sure all your list elements are strings, you can omit `map(str, ...)` and just use `', '.join(l)`

Comment: Thanks so much. Your solutions (including `', '.join(l)` version) work. Just it was hard and confusing for me to debug because `', '.join(l)` in console outputs `\u3000` but not in the real mail message...

Answer (score 3):

If you want to replace the `\u3000` character with a standard space and do the same type of thing for other less common unicode characters, you can use the [unicodedata](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html) module:

```
import unicodedata

jText = """あかさ
あいうえ　お
いい"""

jList = [line.strip() for line in jText.split("\n")] 
    # ['あかさ', 'あいうえ\u3000お', 'いい']

normalizedList = [unicodedata.normalize('NFKC', line) for line in jList]
    # ['あかさ', 'あいうえ お', 'いい']
```